# How does docker scratch container run my app without a shell?

Tags: linux, docker

A docker container based on the `scratch` image lacks a shell.

So how does it run the binary I place inside?

Comment: A shell is just an app like any other. How does the docker container run the shell without a shell?

Comment: Don't go full meta @JörgWMittag! So (turtle) shells all the way down. :)

Comment: The mechanism programs use to start other programs, given an argument vector and a process environment, is `execve`. No shell is required when you have an argument vector. You need a shell when you use an interface like `system()` that takes a shell-syntax string instead of an argument vector -- after which the shell takes that string and _turns it into_ an argument vector, and uses the vector to call `execve()` itself -- _but that's why those interfaces are awful and shouldn't be used_.

Comment: (well, it's a very small subset of why they're awful; `system()` is hard to inject data into without enabling syntax injection attacks; it introduces vulnerabilities like shellshock; it adds performance cost, etc etc etc).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A shell is only needed to run shell scripts or provide an interactive shell session. A container running a binary doesn’t need either of those; it executes the binary given as [the entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) (if specified in `exec` form) without using a shell.

Container setup doesn’t need a shell. A shell isn’t anything special, it’s a binary like any other; the container runtime sets up the “context” for the container, and any binary runs inside that.

To be able to build and run a container without a shell, you need to ensure that all the container directives which run commands ([`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) mentioned above, [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) etc.) all use the `exec` form, *i.e.*

```
ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "arg1", "arg2"]
```

rather than the shell form

```
ENTRYPOINT executable arg1 arg2
```

The latter relies on the shell, and fails if `/bin/sh` (or the shell configured with `SHELL`) isn’t available.

The `exec` form has a number of advantages, beyond not needing a shell: notably, it simplifies signal handling and avoids a number of shell parsing gotchas.

Comment: Thanks. So, in layman's terms, the binary is executed within the host's "context" (my pseudoterm) rather than the container's?

Comment: The binary is executed in the container. A shell isn’t anything special, it’s a binary like any other; the container runtime sets up the “context” for the container, and any binary runs inside that.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a complete answer insofar as it leaves out things like `system()` calls (C's `system()`, Python's `os.system()` or `subprocess.Popen(shell=True)`, and many _many_ other languages' equivalents). Yes, under the hood all of those _are_ "running a" (typically trivial single-command) "shell script" as you describe, but people who use those interfaces don't necessarily know it's doing that; they might see it as more like Microsoft's kernel-level spawn interface that _does_ take a single string as opposed to an argument vector.

Comment: @Charles the whole point here is scenarios where binaries are run *without* using a shell; I’m not sure discussing `system` is relevant (apart from saying “here’s how it could be done with a shell”, but the question isn’t about that).

Comment: @lonix To make Stephen's reply to your question more explicit: No, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @StephenKitt, ...the point is to contrast the way a reader _already knows_ binaries can be started (with a space-separated shell-syntax string) from the way they may not have already known about (with a list of distinct arguments already separated). Pointing out that Docker's two `RUN space-separated command here` vs `RUN ["space-separated", "command", "here" ]` are actually doing different things (the former equivalent to `RUN ["sh", "-c", "space-separated command here"]` is background not every reader will necessarily have.

Comment: I think the detail is informative, but the answer is Stephen's comment *"the container runtime sets up the “context” for the container, and any binary runs inside that"* that's what I didn't understand.